# How to define a constant by expression in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need some like this:

```
const float ratio = 1/60;
```

How to do this?

Comment: Of course, that will just be zero, because you're doing integer division.

Comment: try `const float ratio = 1.0f/60`, or `const float ratio = 1/60.0f`, or even `const float ratio = 1.0f/60.0f`, lest you'll end up with a 0.

Comment: What do you need this for, and what is wrong with `const float ratio = 1/60;`? (besides it being `0.0f`, which is probably not what you want).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need `constexpr`, this will work in `C` or `C++`:

```
const float ratio = 1./60;
```

Comment: +1, but you should probably use a `float` literal instead of `double`.

Comment: I don't think it really makes any difference. If anything, I choose shortest representation - helps for readability.

Comment: Thanks! Works! Stupid mistake.

Comment: I think ./ is not very readable. In some other languages, it means something completely different.

Comment: @Zyx2000: it is very much readable to me (and I am not aware of any other language where `1.` would mean anything different from floating point `1`). You can use `1.0/60` or `1/60.`, but they are both longer. This solution is only one `.` character longer than question.

Answer (score 9):

Exactly as you have done but tell the compiler the values in the expression are floats with a "f" suffix

```
const float ratio = 1.0f/60.0f;
```

Comment: Granted, it is syntactically correct and proper expression of float type. However, I can't help but think this is one of those cases where we are fighting with compiler. Using `1./60` or `1/60.` feels much more readable and natural. And since it is going to be cast to float at compile time anyway, `1./60` is clearly better.

Comment: isn't the OPs original problem that it cast to float *after* doing the division ala `static_cast<float>((int)1 / (int)60)`? I would disagree on "1./60" being clearly better, it honestly looks as much a typo as `1/60.` or `1./60.`

Answer (score 5):

If you need a ratio, as opposed to the result of one, you can use [std::ratio](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio):

```
constexpr one_sixtieth = std::ratio<1, 60>();

constexpr auto n = one_sixtieth.num;
constexpr auto d = one_sixtieth.den;
```

It comes with a set of [useful compile time operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio).

Comment: How does this answer the question? He asked for a flot constant. std::ratio is a compile time fraction

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia My experience tells me that often people ask the wrong question. What they really are asking of for a constant `float` with value `0.f`, but I guess that is not what the really mean :)

Comment: But ... there no other context in the question...

Psychology at work ??

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia exactly. The question no sense, so I have attempted to guess what OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
const float numerator =1;
const float denominator =60;
const float ratio = numerator/denominator;
```

Comment: That's pushing it a little.